# how to post multiple div id values from for loop using jquery / javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display values from an array using for loop in jquery on multiple specific divs. but it is displaying only the last record. however each record is shown in the console log. i tried clearing the variable each time in the loop. but no luck. appreciate every help.

```js
var result = [{"title":"red","sellingPrice":"489","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/p\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"blue","sellingPrice":"481","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/q\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"white","sellingPrice":"482","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/r\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"green","sellingPrice":"492","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/s\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"yellow","sellingPrice":"465","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/t\/itmew9fze83xwhky"}];

  for(var i = 0; i <= result.length-1; i++) {
   document.getElementById('title').innerHTML =result[i].title;
   document.getElementById('price').innerHTML =result[i].sellingPrice;
   document.getElementById('url').innerHTML =result[i].productUrl;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="price"></div>
  <div id="url"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now one more problem. there are other values in the array such as title, price, url etc. and i use div id to display the same. but since i used append, all the values are put next to each other in the first screen. i wanted each of them against its relevant set. The console.log however display correctly. please help

Comment: U are basically only replacing the value in the existing DIVs, You need to create the divs or clone them for every iteration

Comment: you have to inject element using jquery

Comment: Now one more problem. there are other values in the array such as title, price, url etc. and i use div id to display the same. but since i used append, all the values are put next to each other in the first screen. i wanted each of them against its relevant set. The console.log however display correctly. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These divs can repeat multiple time, better is to store each div in separate array. Three divs for three arrays,

```
  var title = [];
  var price = [];
  var url = [];

  var i = 0; 
  $('div #title').each(function(){
    title[i] = $(this).text();
    i++;
  });

var i = 0; 
$('div #price').each(function(){
   price[i] = $(this).text();
   i++;
});

var i = 0; 
$('div #url').each(function(){
   url[i] = $(this).text();
   i++;
});

alert(title);
alert(price);
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: inject the DIVs along with the data

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var result = [{"title":"red","sellingPrice":"489","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/p\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"blue","sellingPrice":"481","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/q\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"white","sellingPrice":"482","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/r\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"green","sellingPrice":"492","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/s\/itmew9fze83xwhky"},
{"title":"yellow","sellingPrice":"465","productUrl":"https:\/\/dl.website.com\/dl\/gn-cm\/t\/itmew9fze83xwhky"}];

        for(var i = 0; i <= result.length-1; i++) {
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'title'+i,
    text: result[i].title
}).appendTo('#container');
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'price'+i,
    text: result[i].sellingPrice
}).appendTo('#container');
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'url'+i,
    text: result[i].productUrl
}).appendTo('#container');    
    }
```

codepen reference:
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/WMdXBw

Answer (score 0):

Its because you overwriting the previous data. If i am correct try get element and add new one.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= result.length-1; i++) {
        document.getElementById('title').innerHTML += result[i].title;
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML += result[i].sellingPrice;
        document.getElementById('url').innerHTML += result[i].productUrl;
        }
```

Or you can use append() method.

Answer (score 0):

use **append ()** on the element with id #container to dynamically add the three divs title, price, url successively on each iteration. Do not forget to delete the id at the level of these three divs.

```
for(var i = 0; i <= result.length-1; i++) {
       $( "#container" ).append( "<div>"+result[i].title+"</div></br>" );
       $( "#container" ).append( "<div>"+result[i].sellingPrice+"</div></br>" );
       $( "#container" ).append( "<div>"+result[i].productUrl+"</div></br>" );
   }
```